# Higgs boson and gravity

Tags: gravity, mass, higgs

I was reading earlier about how Higgs boson (aka The God Particle) is responsible for giving mass certain properties. Among these properties is gravity. What I'm wondering is, by studying Higgs boson, would it be possible, in the future, to maybe create a true [anti-gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-gravity) device?

Comment: I question the sources you've read these from.

Comment: You may want to read over [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33203) and [this one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16206/) in relation to the Higgs Boson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was reading earlier about how Higgs boson (aka The God Particle) is
>   responsible for giving mass certain properties. Among these properties
>   is gravity.

This isn't correct.

For one thing, mass is (classically) a *property* (not an entity that can have properties) while gravity is not a property but is instead an *interaction*.

In the Standard Model, mass is not an intrinsic property of elementary particles but is instead due to interaction with an elementary Higgs *field* that has *[condensed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism#Standard_model)*.

However, this has essentially no connection with gravity for which, as of now, there is no satisfying quantum treatment.

So it is unlikely that study of the Higgs will lead to anti-gravity technology.