# What is common between gravitons and Higgs bozon?

Tags: general-relativity, mass, quantum-gravity, higgs, equivalence-principle

The General Relativity started from the consideration of Einstein that the heavy mass (due to gravitational field and inertial mass (Higgs field) are locally equivalent. What is the connection between gravitational field and Higgs? As far as I know they are two separate fields with not whatever connection with each other. The graviton is of 0 mass and Higgs of GeV's. Why are not the EM field in connection with Higgs or gravitation though?

Comment: In GR, the gravitation interacts with every kind of *energy*, this is not an exclusive interaction with the Higgs field at all. Please keep in mind that intertial mass is NOT equivalent with the mass generated by coupling to the Higgs field... the mass of atoms is heavily dominated by the mass of the proton and the proton's mass itself is largely dominated by binding energy between quarks, NOT by the quarks masses (which come from coupling to the Higgs field.)

Comment: So you confirm my guess that they (GR and Higgs) has nothing in common. Can you answer why Einstein considered them equivalent?

Comment: I do not know what you mean with "Einstein considered GR and Higgs equivalent." GR fulfills all kinds of different equivalence principles (look here for a distinction https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7426), I think you are may referring to them as in your question, but that has nothing to do with the Higgs field or the BEH mechanism. 
Also, Einstein died before the Higgs field was introduced as theoretical idea, so he surely did not consider them equivalent, whatever this means. :-)

Comment: Einstein considered inertial mass (it is due to Higgs 100% true?) = heavy mass (100% due to gravitation, right?). Thats what I mean.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16206/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Mercury No, as I already pointed out in my first comment, mass is not 'due to Higgs 100%', but for everyday objects mostly because of binding energy of quarks inside nucleons.

Comment: @Koschi So most of the inertial mass (99%?) comes from internal energy which is heavy mass due to E=mc2? (and Higgs field has no role what so ever in GR). I would take this for ok, but in.mass and gr.mass are equal to 0.00..001% almost equal experimentally not within 1%?

Comment: @Mercury As I understand it, GR is built on the assumption that *locally* an accelerating frame (in which we care for inertial mass) looks the same as a frame in a gravitational field (in which we care for gravitational mass). This assumption is the namesake for general relativity. Therefore, gravitational mass and inertial mass are the same by default. Now why would you think mass that comes from internal energy behaves different than mass coming from coupling to the Higgs field? In GR there is no distinction between these (& also $g_{\mu\nu}$ generally couples to $T_{\mu\nu}$, not only $m$).